Inequality involving conditional expected values (previous title: Expected value nightmare)
Ok, nightmare may be an exaggeration, but for someone not versed in stochatics, it gets close. I have the following two "composite" random variables:
$$\frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}} \text{ and } \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}}$$
$r_{k},g_{k},r_{j},g_{j}$ are themselves continuous random variables which are i.i.d. Further assumptions could be made, e.g., it would be possible to assume that they have a bounded support. Now, my question is whether it is true that
$$E\left[\;\;r_{k}\;\; \Big \vert\; \frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}} < \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}}\;\right] \leq E\left[\;\;r_{j} \;\Big \vert\; \frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}} < \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}}\;\;\right]?$$
The expressions in the inequality denote the expected values of $r_{k}$ and $r_{j}$, conditional on $\frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}} < \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}}$. If anyone gives a decisive hint, I am happy to mention that person in the acknowledgements of the paper and/or potentially attribute the contribution in a footnote in the proof.

Are you assuming the variables are always positive?  With that assumption, the claim seems intuitive, at least.  But if all of them were negative....

Beyond that issue, I suggest starting by studying the case where the variables are all uniform on $[a,b]$.

Hi @lulu, thank you. Indeed, all random variables are positive, i.e., we can assume that the support is greater than zero. We could assume uniform distribution, though it is quite a restriction -- but if that helps, the assumption could be made. I am not sure, however, that the specific distribution matters here.

Another clickbait title...

This is not a complete answer but I think this is a good start. First, I claim the following:

Let $X, Y$ be two iid continuous random variables. Then $\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Indeed, we have:
$$
    \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{P}(X < y)\bigg\vert_{y = Y}\right] = \mathbb{E}[F(Y)] \end{align*}
$$
where $F$ is the CDF of the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$. But,
$$
   \mathbb{P}(F(Y) \le y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \le F^{-1}(y)) = (F \circ F^{-1})(y) = y \ \forall y \in [0, 1]
$$
i.e, $F(Y) \sim \mathcal{U}[0, 1]$. Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \mathbb{E}[F(Y)] = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Since $r_k, r_j, g_k, g_j$ are iid random variables, it follows that $\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align*}
     \mathbb{E}\left[r_k \bigg\vert \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j} \right] &= 2 \mathbb{E}\left[r_k; \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right]\\
 &= 2 \mathbb{E}\left[r_j; \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j} < \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k}\right]\\
&= 2 \mathbb{E}(r_j) - 2 \mathbb{E}\left[r_j; \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right]\\
&= 2 \mathbb{E}(r_j) - \mathbb{E}\left[r_j \bigg\vert \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right]
\end{align*}
$$
So the claim
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left[r_k \bigg\vert \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j} \right] < \mathbb{E}\left[r_j \bigg\vert \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right]
$$
is equivalent to
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left[r_j \bigg\vert \dfrac{r_k}{r_k + g_k} < \dfrac{r_j}{r_j + g_j}\right] > \mathbb{E}(r_j)
$$

Note. Here I use the notation $\mathbb{E}[X; A] \equiv \mathbb{E}[X \cdot 1_A]$ where $1_A$ is the indicator function. Thus, $\mathbb{E}(X \vert A) = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}(X ; A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$

Hi @Thành, Many thanks for investing so much time into thinking about the problem and coming up with a solution approach. I have already upvoted your answer, and I will most likely award it the green checkmark. However, I first want to understand your argument better. As I mentioned, in case your answer will turn out to be instrumental for solving the problem, I am happy to mention you in the acknowledgements of the paper where this issue is relevant. Cheers, Florian

Hi Thành, could you explain how you get from $$2E[rj;...]$$ to $$2E[rj]-2E[rj;...]?$$

Hi Thành, I have finally proved it myself (I published the proof here). You provided some good transformations, which I weren't aware of and which helped me to do the proof myself. Therefore, I have given you the green checkmark because nobody else engaged with the problem, and I guess that you selflessly invested some of your time into this.

It took me about 20 hours of intense work to solve the problem. I would not be surprised if the statement had applications in multiple contexts. If you want to use the result as a lemma in your own paper, please cite me (contact me at florian.biermann@ntu.ac.uk -- and I will give you the literature reference where this proof was/will be published). Please also contact me if you find the proof in an earlier source, in which case I would cite that source. And, of course, let me know if you think there is an error in the proof.
Let $r_{j},g_{j},r_{k},g_{k}$ be continuous i.i.d. random variables with a support that is a strictly positive bounded interval. It is to be proved that
\begin{equation}\label{fireq}
E\left[\;r_{j}\;\Bigr\vert\; \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}} < \frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}}\right] \leq E\left[\;r_{k}\;\Bigr\vert\; \frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}} < \frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}}\right],
\end{equation}
where $E[\cdot\vert\cdot]$ is the conditional expected value.
Proof. We conduct an equivalent transformation of the condition as follows:
\begin{split}
&\frac{r_{j}}{r_{j}+g_{j}} < \frac{r_{k}}{r_{k}+g_{k}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{r_{j}+g_{j}}{r_{j}} > \frac{r_{k}+g_{k}}{r_{k}} \Leftrightarrow\\ 
&\frac{g_{j}}{r_{j}}+1 > \frac{g_{k}}{r_{k}}+1 \Leftrightarrow g_{k}r_{j} < g_{j}r_{k} 
\end{split}
Let $A$ be the event $g_{k}r_{j} < g_{j}r_{k}$ and $1_{A}$ the indicator function of $A$. Define a new random variable $x := g_{k}r_{j}1_{A}$, and another random variable $y := g_{j}r_{k}1_{A}$. Clearly, it holds $x \leq y$. Therefore, by monotonicity of the expected value operator, we have $E[x] \leq E[y]$, which is $E[g_{k}r_{j}1_{A}] \leq E[g_{j}r_{k}1_{A}]$. This can be written as
$$E[g_{k}r_{j}]E[1_{A}] + Cov(g_{k}r_{j},1_{A}) \leq E[g_{j}r_{k}]E[1_{A}] + Cov(g_{j}r_{k},1_{A}),$$
and because of the i.i.d. assumption, we have $E[g_{k}r_{j}] = E[g_{j}r_{k}]$ so that the inequality becomes
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
Cov(g_{k}r_{j},1_{A}) \leq Cov(g_{j}r_{k},1_{A}).
\end{equation}
We now apply Equation (12) in Bohrnstedt and Goldberger (1969) ("On the exact covariance of products of random variables," Journal of the American Statistical Association, 64(328), pp. 1439-1442), which is
$$Cov(xy,v) = E[x]Cov(y,v)+E(y)Cov(x,v)+E[(x-E[x])(y-E[y])(z-E[z])]$$
for arbitrary random variables $x,y,v$. Setting $x = g_{k}$, $y = r_{j}$, and $v = 1_{A}$ on the left-hand side, and $x = g_{j}$, $y = r_{k}$, and $v = 1_{A}$ on the right-hand side, Inequality (1) becomes
\begin{multline}\tag{2}
E[g_{k}]Cov(r_{j},1_{A})+E(r_{j})Cov(g_{k},1_{A})+E[(g_{k}-E[g_{k}])(r_{j}-E[r_{j}])(1_{A}-E[1_{A}])] \leq\\
E[g_{j}]Cov(r_{k},1_{A})+E(r_{k})Cov(g_{j},1_{A})+E[(g_{j}-E[g_{j}])(r_{k}-E[r_{k}])(1_{A}-E[1_{A}])]
\end{multline}
Because of $g_{k} \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} g_{j}$ and $r_{k} \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim}r_{j}$, we have
$$E[(g_{k}-E[g_{k}])(r_{j}-E[r_{j}])(1_{A}-E[1_{A}]) = E[(g_{j}-E[g_{j}])(r_{k}-E[r_{k}])(1_{A}-E[1_{A}])]$$
so that Inequality (2) is equivalent with
$$E[g_{k}]Cov(r_{j},1_{A})+E[r_{j}]Cov(g_{k},1_{A}) \leq E[g_{j}]Cov(r_{k},1_{A})+E[r_{k}]Cov(g_{j},1_{A}).$$
Because of i.i.d. of all involved random variables, we have $E[g_{k}] = E[r_{j}] = E[g_{j}] = E[r_{k}]$, and we get
\begin{equation}\tag{3} 
Cov(r_{j},1_{A})+Cov(g_{k},1_{A}) \leq Cov(r_{k},1_{A})+Cov(g_{j},1_{A}).
\end{equation}
In the event $A$, which is $g_{k}r_{j} < g_{j}r_{k}$, the random variables $g_{k}$ and $r_{j}$ enter symmetrically. Therefore, we must have $Cov(r_{j},1_{A}) = Cov(g_{k},1_{A})$ and, by the same argument, $Cov(r_{k},1_{A}) = Cov(g_{j},1_{A})$. Inequality (3) is thus equivalent with
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
2Cov(r_{j},1_{A}) \leq 2Cov(r_{k},1_{A}) \Leftrightarrow Cov(r_{j},1_{A}) \leq Cov(r_{k},1_{A}).
\end{equation}
We now turn to the original inequlity we want to prove, which, using the fact that the condition is equivalent with $g_{k}r_{j} < g_{j}r_{k}$, an even that we still denote by $A$, we can write as
\begin{equation}
E[r_{j}1_{A}]/P(A) \leq E[r_{k}1_{A}]/P(A) \Leftrightarrow E[r_{j}1_{A}] \leq E[r_{k}1_{A}].
\end{equation}
This is equivalent with
$$E[r_{j}]E[1_{A}] + Cov(r_{j},1_{A}) \leq E[r_{k}]E[1_{A}] + Cov(r_{k},1_{A})$$
and, by $r_{k} \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim}r_{j}$, equivalent with
$$Cov(r_{j},1_{A}) \leq Cov(r_{k},1_{A}).$$
This is Inequality (4), which we have already proved to be true.
